# Sorting and Mapping Array by time and amount of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, timestamp, mapping

I have the following input of an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    timestamp: 1602754921328,
    product: "productA"
  }, 
  {
    timestamp: 1602754921942,
    product: "productB"
  },
  {
    timestamp: 1602754924160,
    product: "productA"
  },
  {
    timestamp: 1602757547704,
    product: "productB"
  },
  {
    timestamp: 1602757563480,
    product: "productC"
  },
  {
    timestamp: 1602757567032,
    product: "productB"
  }
]
```

where the timestamp is a unix timestamp and the product any string value.
The input array consists of values ranging from start of day to end of day, so 24 hours.

The goal is to split these values into segments of 4 hours, so 6 different segments and have these segments filled with the number of times the value occurred in the array within the 4 hour period.

The expected output would be:

```
[
  {
    name: "productA",
    data: [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
  },
  {
    name: "productB",
    data: [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
  },
  {
    name: "productC",
    data: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
  },
]
```

The output consists of each value that was found in the input array, with an array (let's call it data) consisting of 6 values, where each of these values are the amount of times the value was found in the array for the specific 4 hour period.

I have managed to split the input data into 6 arrays that correspond to the individual 4 hour periods, but I am not sure if this is correct approach for the first step and I am having trouble in getting from this step to the needed output.

Grateful for any directions, I am using javascript to write the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group with the product and get an index fro counting a certain slot of the timestamp.

```js
const
    data = [{ timestamp: 1602754921328, product: "productA" }, { timestamp: 1602754921942, product: "productB" }, { timestamp: 1602754924160, product: "productA" }, { timestamp: 1602757547704, product: "productB" }, { timestamp: 1602757563480, product: "productC" }, { timestamp: 1602757567032, product: "productB" }],
    getIndex = t => Math.floor(Math.floor(t / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24 / 4),
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { timestamp, product: name }) => {
        if (!r[name]) r[name] = { name, data: Array(6).fill(0) };
        r[name].data[getIndex(timestamp)]++;
        return r;
    }, {}));
      
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```